# Accessing Scope Variables in Angular Expression in Jade

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, pug

How do you access a scope variable in an Angular.js expression in a Jade template?

For example: `a(href="/login") Is logged in: {{loggedIn}}`

Shows up as `<a class="ng-binding" href="/login">Is logged in: {{loggedIn}}      </a>`

Comment: Jade variables come from the server - you can't access Angular variables via Jade.

Comment: Right but jade should render to html and angular should fill the expression in with the variable. That's not happening. It's actually displaying the text '{{loggedIn}}'

Comment: If u see {{}} in browser - you either have no angular on page/ there are console errors/this element is not inside ng-app.

Comment: Ok, that was correct, that only showed up on some pages, for which I hadn't created a controller. Now I've made controllers, nothing shows up. I am new to angular.js

Comment: So I think this is actually an issue of sharing data across controllers.

Comment: You may want to consider deleting this question, as the problem has nothing to do with Jade not rendering variables correctly but rather you didn't configure Angular correctly